# Why I can't add a new column in sequelize-cli?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

To add a new column **'avatar'** to the table named **'vdo'**

I just create a miguration file and run it:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('vdo', 'avatar', {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
  },
};
```

but an error appeared like this:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.16.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.11]

Loaded configuration file "database\config.json".
Using environment "development".
(node:9656) [SEQUELIZE0004] DeprecationWarning: A boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
== 20200603081223-add-column: migrating =======

ERROR: Table 'vdo.vdo' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indicate a schema as long as a table name like this:

```
addColumn({ schema: '<your_schema_name_here>', tableName: 'vdo' }, 'avatar', ...
```